# Algolia - How do you avoid having synonyms show up in highlighting?

Tags: algolia

e.g.  "apple" and "orange" are synonyms. I have a searchable attribute named "apple pie". If I search for "orange", the highlight on my attribute is "`<em>orange</em> pie`".

How do I make it show the original attribute value with highlighting: "`<em>apple</em> pie`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option named `replaceSynonymsInHighlight` that you can turn off.

This option can be configured on the index settings or at query time.

You can also change this option form the dashboard under the "Display" tab of your index configuration.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Well named property - not sure how I missed it.